# 2nd "display:table" inside "display: table-cell" sets unwanted margin-top

Tags: html, css

This image shows desired layout:

[image]

"Lorem ipsum" div is placed on top and "Dolor sit" div sits under it. Right "P" div sets minimal height (first part) of whole main wrapper section unless "Dolor sit" div increases height (second part).

Implementation is shown in this Plunker: 
[Plunker demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/p4vqLoWba77yRNklDHyU?p=preview)

```
<section id="wrapperMain" style="display:table; width:100%">
 <div style="background-color:#2e3338; display: table-cell; min-width:50px; width:50px;">
  <h1 style="margin-left:25%; margin-right:25%">P</h1>
 </div>
 <div style="background-color:dodgerblue; display: table-cell;">

  <!--This section should fill its parent: dodgerblue div-->
  <!--So no blue color could be seen above "Lorem ipsum" div-->
  <section style="display:table; width:100%; background-color:crimson; margin-top:0;">
    <div style="display:table-row">
      <div style="background-color:darkslategray;">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #1c1e22; border-style: none; resize: none; width: 100%;">Dolor sit Dolor sit Dolor sit Dolor sit Dolor sit Dolor sit </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

And with any combination of setting margins, heights, displays I wasn't able to dock 2nd table section inside table cell without margin on top. Right now I'm not sure if this is correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are after, you just need to add `vertical-align:top` to the table cell on the right

I have also fixed your second table styles as you had `block` mixed with `table-rows` and no `table-cells` which may cause issues for some browsers:

```html
<section id="wrapperMain" style="display:table; width:100%">
  <div style="background-color:#2e3338; display: table-cell; min-width:50px; width:50px;">
    <h1 style="margin-left:25%; margin-right:25%">P</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:dodgerblue; display: table-cell; vertical-align:top"> <!-- add vertical align:top here -->

    <!--This section should fill its parent: dodgerblue div-->
    <!--So no blue color could be seen above "Lorem ipsum" div-->
    <section style="display:table; width:100%; background-color:crimson; margin-top:0;">
      <div style="display:table-row">
        <div style="background-color:darkslategray; display:table-cell">Lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: #1c1e22; border-style: none; resize: none; width: 100%;display:table-row;">
        <div class="display:table-cell">Dolor sit Dolor sit Dolor sit Dolor sit Dolor sit Dolor sit</div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes! Pete thank you very much, you have no idea how long I've been trying to achieve this!